# Populateing text field and value field of listbox time from SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, listbox

I have a SQL database table that has two columns; 'ID' and 'Names'.
I want to read this data from database and add it into a ListBox with the 'Name' as the new Items text field and the 'ID' as the value field.

This is what I have so far:

```
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString)) {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Name FROM Buildings", conn)) {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                while (reader.Read()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++) {
                        ........................
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up working it out

```
int selectedBuilding = int.Parse(listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedValue));

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionStrin")) {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Name FROM Printers WHERE BuildingID = " + selectedBuilding + "", conn)) {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                conn.Close();

            listBox2.DataSource = dt;
            listBox2.ValueMember = "ID";
            listBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
        }
    }
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Your SQL Query", conn);
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
conn.Close();

ListView1.DataSource = dt;
ListView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks, but still a bit stuck on binding the value and the text fields.